# MODX Вывести 50% ресурсов родителя

Tags: json, cms, modx

Как через pdoresources вывести 50% ресурсов родителя? Количество детей будет постоянно меняться, по этому нужно динамичное решение.
Думаю это можно решить через параметр &last, однако документация скудно описывает этот параметр. https://docs.modx.pro/komponentyi/pdotools/snippetyi/pdoresources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо сначала получить общее кол-во детей, потом вывести 50% их:

```
[[!pdoResources?
&parents=`1532`
&depth=`100`
&hideContainers=`1` 
&showHidden=`1`
&showLog=`0`
&limit=`0`
&tpl=`@INLINE`
&setTotal=`1`
&toPlaceholder=`tempout`
]]
```

Тут важное: `setTotal` - это указать, что надо заполнить плейсхолдер `[[+total]]` с кол-вом ресурсов. `&tpl` - пустой, просто чтобы быстрее обработался, `&toPlaceholder` - чтобы вывод попал в плейсхолдер а не на экран.

От этого вызова мы получаем плейсхолдер `[[+total]]` с количеством детей, дальше вызываем тоже самое но с Вашими шаблонами обертками и т.д., но устанавливаем лимит 50%:

```
[[!pdoResources?
&parents=`1532`
&depth=`100`
&hideContainers=`1` 
&showHidden=`1`
&showLog=`0`
&tpl=`@INLINE [[+id]]`
&limit=[[+total:div=`2`]]
]]
```