# MODX Revo вывод общего кол-ва доп ресурсов?

Tags: modx, revo, pdotools

Продолжаю изучать modx и pdoTools.
У меня есть:

```
-Отец
--Сын 1
---Внук 1
---Внук 2
---Внук 3
---Внук 4
--Сын 2
---Внук 1
---Внук 2
---Внук 3
---Внук 4
--Сын 3
---Внук 1
---Внук 2
---Внук 3
---Внук 4
```

Кол-во сынов и внуков со временем будет расти естественно.

Как подсчитать и вывести кол-во только внуков, используя pdoTools или другой плагин, если он не будет конфликтовать с pdoTools (я просто хз если такое возможно) или системными методами?

Сейчас вывел так для наглядности:

```
[[pdoMenu?
    &parents=`19`
    &level=`0`
    &tpl=`@INLINE <div class="countChildren">[[+children]]</div>`
    &countChildren=`1`
]]
```

В итоге получил:

```
<div class="countChildren">12</div>
<div class="countChildren">4</div>
<div class="countChildren">1</div>
```

Все правильно работает, но как их суммировать? Чтобы в итоге получилось так:

```
<div class="countChildren">17</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо получить общее кол-во внуков:

```
[[!pdoResources?
&parents=`19`
&depth=`100`
&hideContainers=`1` 
&showHidden=`1`
&showLog=`0`
&limit=`0`
&tpl=`@INLINE`
&setTotal=`1`
&toPlaceholder=`tempout`
]]

<div class="countChildren">[[+total]]</div>
```

Тут важное: `setTotal` - это указать, что надо заполнить плейсхолдер `[[+total]]` с кол-вом ресурсов. `&tpl` - пустой, просто чтобы быстрее обработался, `&toPlaceholder` - чтобы вывод попал в плейсхолдер а не на экран.

От этого вызова мы получаем плейсхолдер [[+total]] с количеством внуков

Это первая часть моего же ответа [MODX Вывести 50% ресурсов родителя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/925970/modx-%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-50-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f/925998#925998)

Comment: Спасибо. Это работает, но считает почему то на единицу больше (должно быть 17, а выводит 18) и второе - напрягает &depth = `100`, а если внуков будет больше 100? 200 например? Или 200 только в одном сыне, а во втором 300 и уже будет выводить неверную цифру?

Comment: `depth` - это глубина вложенности 100 уровней отец-сын-правнук-праправнук-прапрапра(100раз)правнук, можете поставить хоть 100000. По поводу счета скорее всего где-то у сына у вас не поставлен контейнер, т.е. вложенные ресурсы есть но не конейнер - и соответственно попадает в подсчет. Попробуйте добавить параметр  `&returnIds` = `1` и убрать &toPlaceholder=`tempout` - получите список ресурсов участвующих в подсчете, смотрите какой лишний попадает и почему

Comment: Спасибо Вам огоромное

Comment: не подскажите как вывести на странице порядковый номер внука, в котором нахожусь? Например нахожусь в первом внуке первого сына отца и тут вывести цифру один

Comment: Разные вопросы лучше задавать в разных темах. Создайте новый вопрос, и сформулируйте его поподробнее: что к примеру должен вывести во втором внуке первого отца и в первом внуке второго отца.