# Modx revo слайдер на owl-carousel в два ряда

Tags: modx, owl-carousel

Есть верстка слайдера такого вида:

```
<div class="owl-carousel brand-slider">
        <a href="#" class="brands__link"><img src="img/miele.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href="#" class="brands__link"><img src="img/miele.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href="#" class="brands__link"><img src="img/miele.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href="#" class="brands__link"><img src="img/miele.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href="#" class="brands__link"><img src="img/miele.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href="#" class="brands__link"><img src="img/miele.png" alt=""></a>

    </div>
```

Вывожу:

```
[[pdoResources?
&tpl=`Brands-index`
&sortdir=`ASC`
&limit=`0`
&depth=`0`
&parents=`5`
&includeTVs=`Brand-image`]]
```

есть чанк Brands-index:

```
<a href="[[+uri]]" class="brands__link"><img src="[[+tv.Brand-image]]" alt=""></a>
```

иTV Brand-image с изображением.
Сейчас все выводится в одну строку, надо, что бы в две строки, то есть 3 картинки в одной строке и три в другой...если ссылок меньше, например 5, то три вверху, две внизу. Как это можно сделать?

1 3 5
2 4 6

Comment: Напишите сколько должно выводиться в первой и второй строке в зависимости от кол-ва ссылок? например если их 4 или 8?

Comment: Если их 4 или 8, то соответственно либо по две, либо по 4. В посте в конце описал цифрами ,в каком порядке должны идти слайды, если их, к примеру 6

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, что вопрос перекликается с этим: [MODX Вывести 50% ресурсов родителя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/925970/modx-%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-50-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f) только там надо было вывести половину страниц, а вам надо половину в первой строке и оставшуюся часть во второй. Поэтому приведу тот ответ здесь, немного изменив:

Вам надо сначала получить общее кол-во картинок, потом вывести первую половину, потом вторую:

```
[[!pdoResources?
&parents=`5`
&depth=`0`
&limit=`0`
&tpl=`@INLINE`
&setTotal=`1`
&toPlaceholder=`tempout`
]]
```

Тут важное: `setTotal` - это указать, что надо заполнить плейсхолдер `[[+total]]` с кол-вом ресурсов. `&tpl` - пустой, просто чтобы быстрее обработался, `&toPlaceholder` - чтобы вывод попал в плейсхолдер а не на экран.

От этого вызова мы получаем плейсхолдер `[[+total]]` с количеством картинок, дальше вызываем с Вашими шаблонами обертками и т.д., но устанавливаем лимит 50%:

```
[[!pdoResources?
&parents=`5`
&depth=`0`
&limit=`0`
 &tpl=`Brands-index`
&sortdir=`ASC`
&includeTVs=`Brand-image`
&limit=[[+total:div=`2`]]
]]
```

Дальше выводим вторую половину, используя оператор `offset` (смещение)

```
[[!pdoResources?
&parents=`5`
&depth=`0`
&limit=`0`
 &tpl=`Brands-index`
&sortdir=`ASC`
&includeTVs=`Brand-image`
&offset=[[+total:div=`2`]]
]]
```

Подробная документация о pdoResources: https://docs.modx.pro/komponentyi/pdotools/snippetyi/pdoresources